# Same permissions Facebook app

Tags: android, ios, facebook

Currenly I have an Facebook app. I want to create a IOS and Android app as well. Does the user need to give permissions again and can I use the same information that is available on the Facebook app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, once your facebook app asks for user to give permission (which fires the browser if facebook app is not installed on the mobile, and the facebook app if installed), if your app is already approved by the user - and you're not asking for further permissions than were approved by the user on your web app - your mobile app will be approved automatically.

The behavior should be as follows:

- **If the user is not currently logged in to facebook** (on the facebook app or mobile web). When the user runs your app for the first time, your app calls the login API, either facebook app or the browser opens (on iOS, you see the window sliding out and the facebook app slides in). The user will be prompted to log in. After logging in, control will be switched back to your app.
- **If the user *is* currently logged in to facebook**. When the user runs your app for the first time, your app calls the login API, either facebook app or the mobile browser opens. Shortly afterwards, without any user intervention, the it will switch back to your app (on iOS, you'll just see the windows sliding twice - out of your app and in again).